# Put a loading stuff when Datagridview/Listview loading data from the database because of UI performance

Tags: c#, multithreading, listview, datagridview

Hello guys I am new here in stackoverflow so the problem is my UI always freeze when the Listview is still loading up data from my database even I already have a new thread for it so I believe that I have to put a loading stuff here.

So basically when the my listview is still loading up data , I would like to put a loading like "0 of out 100 " like that or .gif loading image is enough.

Check for the code that I've already made:

```
public BookManager()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ParameterizedThreadStart pts = new ParameterizedThreadStart(LoadBooks);
        Thread t = new Thread(pts);
        t.Start();
    }

 public void LoadBooks(object state)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
        this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
        try
        {
            listView1.Clear();
            ImageList myImageList1 = new ImageList();
            myImageList1.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;

            listView1.LargeImageList = myImageList1;
            listView1.LargeImageList.ImageSize = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 80);



            MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from booktable";
            MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            adap.Fill(ds);

            for (int i = 0;i<ds.Rows.Count;i++)
            {
                byte[] byteBLOBData = (byte[])ds.Rows[i]["bookphoto"];
                var stream = new MemoryStream(byteBLOBData);

                Image bookimages = Image.FromStream(stream);

                myImageList1.Images.Add(bookimages);

                    ListViewItem lsvparent = new ListViewItem();
                    lsvparent.Text = ds.Rows[i]["booktitle"].ToString();
                    listView1.Items.Add(lsvparent.Text, i);

            }
           catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        finally
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        }));
    }
```

Comment: The `Invoke` method executes the code on the UI thread. So the thread you create is not really used.

Comment: So where do you think should I put the Invoke method sir?

Answer (score 0):

As I commented it previously, the `Invoke` method executes the code on the UI thread. So the thread you create is not really used : most of the work is done on the UI thread.

I would suggest you to try something like that :

```
public BookManager()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ParameterizedThreadStart pts = new ParameterizedThreadStart(LoadBooks);
    Thread t = new Thread(pts);
    t.Start();
}

public void LoadBooks(object state)
{
    ImageList myImageList1 = null;
    Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        listView1.Clear();
        myImageList1 = new ImageList();
        myImageList1.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;

        listView1.LargeImageList = myImageList1;
        listView1.LargeImageList.ImageSize = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 80);
    }));

    MySqlConnection connection = null;
    try
    {
        connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
        connection.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from booktable";
        MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable ds = new DataTable();
        adap.Fill(ds);

        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            byte[] byteBLOBData = (byte[])ds.Rows[i]["bookphoto"];
            var stream = new MemoryStream(byteBLOBData);

            Image bookimages = Image.FromStream(stream);

            Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                myImageList1.Images.Add(bookimages);
                ListViewItem lsvparent = new ListViewItem();
                lsvparent.Text = ds.Rows[i]["booktitle"].ToString();
                listView1.Items.Add(lsvparent.Text, i);
            }));
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection != null && connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow it works , Im glad that you help me a lot , so the problem that I'm going to face is I would like to put a loading stuff, Do you have any idea , so I can trick the user when it still loading up?

Comment: What do you mean by loading stuff ? Do you want to hide the listView, replace the images by a temporary loading image, ... ?